# iOS 15.1 UserDialogs library does not display wheel date picker

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

Hi guys I have an issue with the latest version of iOS 15.1. I noticed that my Navigation bar disappeared when I compile the code with Xcode 13, also the wheel date picker now shows as a calendar when I use the ACR UserDialog. Does anyone know how I can solve this?
I want it to show as Wheel picker

```
var result = await UserDialogs.Instance.DatePromptAsync();
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this you need to set the style for iOS `DatePicker` using `DatePromptConfig` like below:

```
DatePromptConfig datePromptConfig = new DatePromptConfig();
datePromptConfig.iOSPickerStyle = iOSPickerStyle.Wheels; //wheel picker style
var result = await UserDialogs.Instance.DatePromptAsync(datePromptConfig);
```